# How do I create a separate page for each author?

Tags: pages, templates, author

I am working on a website where I have authors listed on a custom-made author's page using code adapted from this site: http://bavotasan.com/2011/an-even-better-author-list-in-wordpress/.

When you click the avatars now, they take you to another individual author page that returns all the blog posts that author has written.

How do I make it so that everytime you click on an author avatar, it takes you to a page with a larger version of the avatar, their description, and their recent comments and posts; instead of just their posts.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Create an `author.php` template by copying your themes `archive` template to start with. Then you can modify it as you wish.

Wordpress will use this author template for every author on your site automatically
As an example visit damien.co/author/damiensaunders

Note you may have to change your authors names as Damien (space) Saunders doesn't become damien%20saunders as part of the author URL

See [Author Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates) in Codex.

Comment: I have an author.php page which lists all the authors. How do I go from that to a separate page from each author? I would like the avatars to link to these separate pages...

Comment: `author.php` is a single author template, your author list should be a different page.

Comment: How would I link to the author page from my author list page? Many thanks for your help, Milo.

Comment: your author list already does that with `get_author_posts_url($author['ID']);`

Comment: If you look at my original question: I don't want to show just recent posts on that page -- on each individual page, I want: the avatar again; the description of the author; recent posts AND recent comments...

Comment: perhaps you misunderstand my answer. `get_author_posts_url` outputs the url to that author's page from your list of all authors, on that page (`author.php` template) you can edit how you wish to add avatar, posts, comments, etc.. If you're already using the `author.php` template to output your list of all authors, you are using the wrong template for this purpose.

Comment: @Chilli what you want is all possible with theme development. I just did a Google for WordPress Author Template and found this tutorial http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-wordpress-authors-page-template/